# simplify $\log(x^k(1-x)^{n-k}) - \log(x^k(1-x)^{n-k} + (1-x)^k x^{n-k}) - \log(0.5))$ for $x \in (0,1)$

Tags: probability, logarithms, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients, information-theory

simplify $\log(x^k(1-x)^{n-k}) - \log(x^k(1-x)^{n-k} + (1-x)^k x^{n-k}) - \log(0.5))$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $k \leq n$

$\textbf{context:}$

I am trying to solve a certain equation in the following form, where $a \in \{-1,1\}$ and $q_a \in [0,1]$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{a} p(a)\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} q_{a}^k(1-q_{a})^{n-k}  \Bigg[ \log(q_a^k \cdot (1-q_a)^{n-k}) \nonumber - \Bigg(\log\bigg( q_1^{k}(1-q_1)^{n-k}p(a=1)+ q_{-1}^{k}(1-q_{-1})^{n-k}p(a=-1)\bigg)\Bigg)\Bigg]
\end{align}

The following properties are given:

1) $p(a = 1) = p(a=-1) = \frac{1}{2}$

2) $q_{1} = 1-q_{-1}$

Using these properties we can deduce that the term in the big brackets can be reduces to:

$\log(x^k(1-x)^{n-k}) - \log(x^k(1-x)^{n-k} + (1-x)^k x^{n-k}) - \log(0.5))$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $k \leq n$ where $x$ is $q_{1}$ or $q_{-1}$

$\textbf{What i have tried:}$

1) Using taylor expansions, however the right hand term was very complicated thus i eventually did not see any simplifaction in that matter.

2) Trying to find an approximation by using facts as $log(1+x) \approx x$ for small $x$, hower the right hand term still gave me a lot of complications.

3) Plot terms for all possible $n$ and $k$, this methods resulted in nice plots, however i did not seem to find a relation or some sort of fit of the function to k.

$\textbf{My question to you}$

Have i missed out a method that i should try? Is it able to simplify this formula to a simpler form?

With kind regards,

Kees Til

Comment: It seems you can rewrite it as:
$$k\ln(x)-\ln(x^{2k-n}+(1-x)^{2k-n})-\ln(0.5)$$
is it useful ?

Comment: it helps a lot thanks, i dont see however how your term $(n-k)ln(1-x)$ seems to cancel out somewhere?

Comment: It was for the version with $\ln(x^n(1-x)^{n-k})$ as the first term ^^"

Comment: i am sorry that was a typo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it useful to you but you have:
\begin{align}
\ln\left(x^k (1-x)^{n-k} \right)-\ln\left(x^k (1-x)^{n-k} +x^{n-k} (1-x)^{k} \right)&=-\ln\left(\frac{x^k (1-x)^{n-k} +x^{n-k} (1-x)^{k}}{x^k (1-x)^{n-k}} \right)\\
&=-\ln\left(1+x^{n-k-k} (1-x)^{k-n+k} \right)\\
&=-\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{n-2k} \right)\\
\end{align}

Comment: this actually helped a lot!

Comment: I reduced the formula to this form:

$$
1 - \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} q_{1}^{k}(1-q_{1})^{n-k} \log(1+\left(\frac{q_1}{1-q_1}\right)^{n-2k})
$$